# What is Ext.id()?

Tags: extjs

I could not find it in the API documentation or any explanation on different Internet search engine query results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the function that ExtJS uses internally to generate unique IDs for DOM elements that are created by ExtJS. From my console at http://www.sencha.com:

```
> Ext.id
  function (e,D){return(e=Ext.getDom(e)||{}).id=e.id||(D||"ext-gen")+(++h)}
> Ext.id()
  "ext-gen22"
> Ext.id()
  "ext-gen23"
> Ext.id()
  "ext-gen24"
```

#### From the source

See [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext) (scroll down to `Public Methods -> id`) and [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext.html#method-Ext-id).

```
/**
     * Generates unique ids. If the element already has an id, it is unchanged
     * @param {Mixed} el (optional) The element to generate an id for
     * @param {String} prefix (optional) Id prefix (defaults "ext-gen")
     * @return {String} The generated Id.
     */
    id : function(el, prefix){
        el = Ext.getDom(el, true) || {};
        if (!el.id) {
            el.id = (prefix || "ext-gen") + (++idSeed);
        }
        return el.id;
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

One helpful thing that I've done in the past if you need to generate a unique ID for whatever reason, is just to do something like:

```
var id = Ext.id();
id = parseInt(id.replace("ext-gen", ""));
return id;
```

That'll get rid of the "ext-gen" part of the String that Ext.id() returns and give you an int (if you need it).

Answer (score 1):

For unique ID number you can also just do:

```
   var uniqueId = ++Ext.idSeed;
```